# Android - How to make blocks with content, simular to post-block in facebook's app

Tags: android

I am working on simple app, similar to Instagram, Facebook app or G+ app. I want to make board with other users posts. The posts on board will be displayed in bocks, simular to Facebook:
[image: This is what i mean by block]

How should i create such blocks, that i can fill with downloaded data and add up to the board, modify them or remove them from board while user is still in board activity? Is there any class that i could use?

Comment: Have a look at RecyclerView and cards https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look at [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

It lets you maintain a list of objects and build views from visible ones, add more dynamically etc.

As for the actual block.. Depends on how you want to display them. I hope you know about View types such as LinearLayout etc, if not you should probably read some basic guide for android programming before you begin.